# How to change style of ant design in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, antd

I can't change style in ant-tooltip on nuxtjs. I access to class ant-tooltip-inner but it don't changing.

```
<div class="box-form-input">
     <a-tooltip placement="topRight" trigger="focus">
         <template slot="title">
             <span>Please fill in your Fullname</span>
         </template>
         <a-input
             v-model="full_name"
      
         />
     </a-tooltip>
</div>
<style>
    .ant-tooltip-inner {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Overriding the native ant-design styles requires some configuration work. You should usually never use the ant-design class names for it. If you use babel and Webpack, I go over it in this blog post : https://medium.com/@syllaband/theming-ant-design-a-detailed-step-by-step-basic-guide-d060bef34ec4

Answer (score 1):

Overriding Antd tooltip in `vue.js` works as expected.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- remove h3 tag causes wrong arrow direction -->
    <h3>try to remove this element.
      <br>After removed, the tooltip arrow changed direction.
    </h3>
    <a-tooltip placement="left" title="wrong arrow direction">
      <span>why don't use popper.js</span>
    </a-tooltip>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.ant-tooltip-inner {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

See working [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-vue-tooltip-forked-zq9or?file=/src/App.vue).